# No privileges in meta help

Tags: support, meta, privileges

I was looking at the help pages and noticed that the privileges section is blank. Should we add something here?

Answer (score 6):

All per-site metas don't have anything in the privileges page. Per-site meta privileges reflect those that you have on the main site.

I believe that this has to do with the fact that you can't earn reputation on Meta, and thus a privilege page for it would be somewhat unneeded and weird.